# OdataModel V2 metadataFailed event not thrown in Firefox

Tags: odata, sapui5

I noticed that the metadataFailed event described in API sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel is not thrown on firefox.

I have created a JSBin to reproduce the problem.

http://jsbin.com/vusesuvuge/1/edit?html,console

The following code triggers the metadataFailed in Chrome browser, but does not work in any Firefox browser. Anyone a solution or explanation for this problem ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"     
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_blue_crystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
    data-sap-ui-debug="true"
  ></script>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>oData and table test</title>
  <script>

    var url = "http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders";

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url).attachMetadataFailed(function(){
      alert('fail');
    })




  </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add type="text/javascript" to your script tag and try.

Comment: Adding  type="text/javascript" to script tag has no effect. Still not working in Firefox

Comment: remove your browser add-ons and check, re-install firebug and check.

Comment: Removed all addons and browser restart has no effect. Event is still not thrown.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 57.0.1 (64-Bit) But also with older version it does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161699/discussion-between-santhosh-and-francesco-iannazzo).